# wp_update_post function exclude specific field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a function to update the default post and this function updates the language post publish date and some fields. it's working fine but the problem is that our meta_post field "_mydomain" also updates value like the default post. is it possible I only exclude this meta_post field? i don't want to change this value from this function

```
foreach ( array_slice( $languages, 1 ) as $language ) {
    $updatess = array(
        'ID' => $language, 
        'post_date' => $timeD, 
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $timeD ) 
    );

    wp_update_post( $updatess );

    if ( ! empty( $version ) ) {
        update_field('version', $version , $language );    
    }          
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like `wp_update_post` executes any hooks; but it calls `wp_insert_post` at the end, and that one executes several - so you could try and fix your data in there. Would perhaps make more sense though, if you _read_ the meta value from the current post, and then put it into your `$updatess` data structure - so that it will "update" again with the already set current value.